# MySQL make two columns UNIQUE

Tags: mysql

Don't know if this is possible for MySQL because I know that it doesn't support check constraints, but what I want is to make two columns unique. Before you answer with

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD UNIQUE(<col1>, <col2>);
```

That's not what I want. I would like to ensure that col1 and col2 have unique values so if they are INTs, number "1" can exist only once between both columns, which means if col1 contains "1", col2 cannot contain "1" and "1" can only appear once in col1. Hopefully that makes sense.

I know I can do it from a php level, but right now there is a lot of code, and if I miss a spot, I don't want to destroy data integrity; I rather throw an error from the database. Some ideas that I've come across is using triggers. If someone can give me an example of using triggers to accomplish this, that would be great.

### UPDATE

It might help if you knew what I was doing, then maybe you can propose a better way of doing this:

I have two fields, email and new_email. When someone changes their email address, I store it into the new_email field until the accept the change. Since email is unique because it's used as their login, I HAVE to ensure that the email is unique across both fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to reorganize your database. Let's say currently you have this:

```
Table: users

id   name   email          new_email
102  foo    foo@mail.com   foo2@mail.com
103  bar    bar@mail.com   bar2@mail.com
104  baz    baz@mail.com   NULL
```

This could be changed to:

```
Table: users

id   name
102  foo
103  bar
104  baz

Table: emails

user_id  is_new  email
102      0       foo@mail.com
102      1       foo2@mail.com
103      0       bar@mail.com
103      1       bar2@mail.com
104      0       baz@mail.com
```

You can then add a unique index on the final table on the column `email`.

Comment: So triggers are slow? I've never used them because I come from an MSSQL background where we can use constraints. As for the cols, please read the update. I should have added that initially, but I was too scatter-brained.

Comment: @JohnathanKong: Actually I changed my mind a bit about the speed - I think both solutions will offer reasonable performance if done correctly. However I think it's easier to do it correctly if you use the approach I have shown in my answer.

Comment: I think this is the best approach. I'll modify my model and user to do it this way. It'll be somewhat odd, but the good thing is that it'll give me historical data as well on the changes that the user has made to their email.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

1. Create a table `MakeColsUnique` with one column `ColumnBoth`
2. Create a Primary Key on `ColumnBoth`
3. All all values from `Col1` and `Col2` to this table (if you have existing duplicates, this will fail)
4. Add a trigger on OriginalTable on INSERT or UPDATE to insert the value from Col1 and Col2 into the new table `MakeColsUnique`

If the value has already been inserted, the insert or update will fail.

Comment: Although Mark's solution is nicer as a model, this solution is pretty creative if you can't change the existing model anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can't enforce that with a key constraint.  Honestly the requirement sounds a little bit odd, and I think you're probably better off extracting col1 and col2 into a separate table, say cols.

Comment: what they will be used for are two columns, email and new_email. When someone changes their email I store their new email into the new_email field until they accept this change. The email MUST be unique between both because the email must be unique.

Comment: If you have a need to store multiple email ids, I think you should create a new table called UserEmailIds and put all user emails in there.

Comment: I'd still have the same problem because I need to ensure that the is uniqueness between both columns. It doesn't matter how many tables I use. Unless I'm missing something

Comment: As Raj said, you can, and probably should put that in a separate table.  You can have a "new" boolean field and enforce a unique constraint across (userid, new) so that a user can have at most two e-mails, one old and one new.  You can also enforce a unique constraint across e-mails.

Comment: @Mark Byers's answer is exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

As per you update on the question a database constraint is not a valid option, because you want to store the email for a while in both the fields and then accept it once the user accepts it. It looks more like a logic that needs to be implemented in the application business logic than the database

Comment: Yea, I was thinking of preventing at the model level, I'm using codeigniter, but the problem is I want to prevent doing a select inside the model before inserting. That will probably be my last resort.

Comment: Selecting before inserting the value and validation is the best resort I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem? I have encountered this problem too, and finally I solve my problem with trigger, following your idea. Here is my sql:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER unique_AB BEFORE INSERT ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
         DECLARE msg varchar(200);  
     DECLARE flag int;
     set flag = (select count(*) from test where A = new.A or B = new.A or A = new.B or B = new.B);
     IF flag > 0 THEN
        set msg = "column duplicate!!!";  
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;  
     END IF;
  END;
|
```

my table is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `A` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `B` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

in the trigger, I made a select first and judge if there is already a value that is equals to my new line, and this worked for me.